# Evaluation of $\lim_{x \to k\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-k\pi)}$ from the Weierstrass product expansion of $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

Consider the Weierstrass infinite product expansion of the $\sin(x)$ function:
$$ \tag 1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
 = \prod_{n=0}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2 \pi^2} \right)
 = \prod_{n\neq 0}  \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n \pi} \right). $$
Moreover, it is easily shown that, given an integer $k \neq 0$,
$$ \tag 2 \lim_{x \to k \pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-k\pi)} = \frac{(-1)^k}{k\pi}. $$
I wanted to obtain **(2)** from the expansion **(1)**. However, I seem to get a wrong result, and I'm not finding the mistake in my reasoning.

Starting from **(1)**, I write
$$ \tag 3 \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-k\pi)}
 = \frac{k\pi - x}{k\pi(x-k\pi)} \prod_{n \neq k,0} \frac{n\pi - x}{n\pi}
 = -\frac{1}{k\pi} \prod_{n \neq k,0} \frac{n\pi - x}{n\pi}, $$
and taking the limit $x \to k \pi$ I have:
$$ \tag 4 \lim_{x \to k \pi}  \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-k\pi)} 
 = - \frac{1}{k\pi} \prod_{n\neq k,0} \frac{n-k}{n} = \frac{1}{k\pi}.$$
The last step comes from the following considerations:
$$ \tag 5 \prod_{n \neq k,0} (n-k) = \frac{1}{(-k)} \prod_{n \neq 0} n, $$
$$ \tag 6 \prod_{n \neq k,0} n = \frac{1}{k} \prod_{n \neq 0} n,$$
$$ \tag 7 \prod_{n\neq k,0} \frac{n-k}{n} = \frac{k}{-k} = -1.$$

Where did I go wrong?
To be more specific, I know how to obtain the result **(2)** directly, I'm trying to do it from the infinite product expansion as an exercise to try the formula.

If the problem is in my "splitting" up non-convergent components of the product, I would also like to know what is the correct handle this kind of calculation.

Comment: Can you say how you got $\prod_{n\ne k,0}\frac{n-k}n=-1$?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski see the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show it using Weierstrass product, this is a way$$\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x\left(x-k\pi\right)}=\frac{1}{x-k\pi}\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{x-k\pi}\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\left(\frac{\left(n\pi-x\right)\left(n\pi+x\right)}{n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)=-\frac{k\pi+x}{k^{2}\pi^{2}}\underset{n=1,n\neq k}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\left(\frac{\left(n\pi-x\right)\left(n\pi+x\right)}{n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)=-\frac{k\pi+x}{k^{2}\pi^{2}}\underset{n=1,n\neq k}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\left(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)\underset{x\rightarrow k\pi}{\longrightarrow}-\frac{2}{k\pi}\underset{n=1,n\neq k}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\left(1-\frac{k^{2}}{n^{2}}\right).$$
 It remain to show that $$\underset{n=1,n\neq k}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\left(1-\frac{k^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{2}$$
 and you can find a proof here [How can I show that $\prod_{{n\geq1,\, n\neq k}} \left(1-\frac{k^{2}}{n^{2}}\right) = \frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142703/closed-form-for-a-infinite-product) .

Answer (score 2):

You can't say that the two products in (5) are equal because neither one is convergent. You have the same issue with line (6).

In order to evaluate, $\prod_{n\ne k,0}\frac{n-k}n$, you might try to write it as $\prod_{n\ne k,0}\left(1-\frac kn\right)$.

Comment: About the first identity, I think it makes more sense how I wrote it: you have the product of all non-zero integers, except for $-k$. The way you wrote it it would be zero because $n=0$ is in the product. Anyway I understand that the expression is meaningless anyway because divergent. Any thoughts on how to evaluate the last term you wrote?

Comment: My best guess is to apply $\log$ to it, then expand each term using Taylor series. I'm not sure if that will help as I don't have access to pen and paper atm.

Comment: Why do you state that one will "need" to write the product as $\prod\left(1-\frac{k}n\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a translation:
$$ \lim_{x\to k\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-k\pi)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+k\pi)}{x(x+k\pi)}=\frac{(-1)^k}{k\pi}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\color{red}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k\pi}}.$$

Comment: I know how to obtain the result directly. I am trying to get it from the infinite product expansion as an exercise

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my derivation is in taking separately the limits of divergent expressions, as already pointed out in the accepted answer. Here is a way to prove directly that
$$ \prod_{n \neq 0,k} \frac{n-k}{n} = (-1)^{k+1}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}, $$
completing the last step of my derivation (the concept is very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1143205/173147)):

$$ \prod_{n \neq 0,k} \frac{n-k}{n}
 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac
  {(-N-k)(-N-k+1)\cdots(-k-1)(-k+1)\cdots(-1)(+1)\cdots(N-k)}
  {-N(-N+1)\cdots(-1)(+1)\cdots(k-1)(k+1)\cdots N}
 \\ = \frac{(-1)^{N+k}}{-k} \lim_{N \to \infty}  \left( \frac
  {(N+k)! (N-k)!}
  {-N(-N+1)\cdots(-1)(+1)\cdots(k-1)(k+1)\cdots N} \right)
 \\ = \frac{(-1)^{N+k}}{-k} k(-1)^N \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac
  {(N+k)! (N-k)!}
  {(N!)^2}
 = (-1)^{k+1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The products you are working with are not absolutely convergent : you can't sum the terms in the order you want. I'd guess that's why you don't get the correct answer.